# ProgressBar не показывается после установки visibility="gone"

Tags: android, kotlin

Не могу понять, почему не показывается `ProgressBar`. В layout он изначально установлен так:

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="@style/AppTheme"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

В коде у него меняется android:visibility на `true` при нажатии на кнопку, и на `false` после прихода данных - при этом между нажатием на кнопку и приходом данных достаточно много времени - я ставила задержку до 10 секунд, и всё равно `ProgressBar` вообще не виден.

```
class ActorActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actor_details)
        val moreBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.more_btn)
        val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressbar)
        moreBtn.setOnClickListener {
            progressBar.isVisible = true
            viewModel.getMoreInfo(actor.name)
        }
        viewModel.actor.observe(this, Observer<Actor> {
            progressBar.isVisible = false
        })
    }
}
```

При этом если не устанавливать в layout у `ProgressBar` изначально

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

то он виден.

**UPD:** полная разметка с `ProgressBar`-ом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/more_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:text="@string/more_btn_label"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/avatar" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="@style/AppTheme"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/double_margin"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/more_btn"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/avatar"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: я бы советовал из кода управлять видимостью, у меня например тоже конфликтовал xml и класс активности

Comment: Может `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, пробовала, но всё то же самое

Comment: Очень странно, единственное на что влияет `gone` - это на пространство для других элементов. Покажите полностью разметку.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, добавила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я выяснила наконец, в чём дело. Это всё-таки был мой недочёт: я вызывала

```
Thread.sleep(1000L)
```

из main-потока, и останавливало main-поток, потому и прогрессбар не успевал показаться. Как только я вынесла эту строку в бэкграунд, прогрессбар стал виден.

Натолкнул меня на мысль [ответ на похожий вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46176274/4898850).

> thread sleep. --> this is stopping the UI thread and the view has no
>   time to update the visibility because it's stopped

Answer (score 0):

Это известная фича/баг `ConstraintLayout` связанная с особенностями данного лейаута именно c `visibility=gone`. Как известно если `visibility=gone` то менеджер лейаута рассчитывает положение элементов, так как будто данного элемента нет - иногда это удобно, иногда не очень.

Общего рецепта как с этим бороться нет (я, по крайней мере, не знаю).

Народ выкручивается как может - предлагают через `android:layout_weight` или `android:layout_width=0dp` или вообще сменой на `RelativeLayout` или `visibility=invisible`

Погуглите, пробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но в моём конкретном случае всё-таки причина оказалась в другом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1056363/189882